# How to select and display row of an empty value in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with 2 columns, let's say that it is Column1 and Column2. In Column 1 there is one row that has no value while in Column2 all rows have a value.
Here's an example:

```
Column1 | Column2
-----------------
   A    |    1 
   B    |    2 
        |    3 
   D    |    4 
   E    |    5
```

I want to display the names of Rows in Column1 whose value = null or "".

Here's my code

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM table_Sample
WHERE Column1 = NULL;
```

but it is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "It is wrong"? Is there an error? Do you not get the results you were expecting?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to display the rows whose `Column1` values are Null or "" (empty string).

Concatenate an empty string to `Column1` value, and check whether the length of the resulting string is zero.

```sql
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM table_Sample
WHERE Len(Column1 & '') = 0;
```

When `Column1` is Null, concatenating an empty string will produce an empty string, and its length is zero.

When `Column1` is an empty string, concatenating an empty string will produce an empty string, and its length is zero.